# Where is DocuSign's embedded form front-end bundle documentation?

Tags: docusignapi

I need to affect some branding tweaks on an embedded DocuSign form & for the life of me I can't find any actual documentation on the front-end bundle referred to here:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/#docusign-js

Specifically, I need to change the wording on the other buttons (aside from `style.signingNavigationButton.finishText` which is in all the examples).

Searching the internet and combing DocuSign's dev documentation for hours.

Answer (score 0):

You want the branding file. See the [docs](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=yum1583277332870.html)

Note that not all DocuSign plans include full branding.

The [branding guidelines](https://docusign.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#300000000bS4/a/1W0000008xe5/A4O4A4AFP6988Cz2ZFzhvJusbXHfMd3oUxJ8NZhyCZA) are also important.

**Note: the page loads slowly**

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for me.  I don't have access to the branding.  Only the bundle api.